# Генерация pdf - библиотека TCPDF

Tags: php

Нужно чтобы создался пдф, с картинкой на фоне и текстом на поверх этой картинки. Я делаю так:

```
<?

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bitrix/php_interface/pdf/config/lang/eng.php");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bitrix/php_interface/pdf/tcpdf.php");

// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // set bacground image
        $img_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/holiday2012/happynewyearagat.png';
        $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 051');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);

// remove default footer
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 48);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Print a text
$html = '<span style="background-color:yellow;color:blue;">&nbsp;PAGE 1&nbsp;</span>
<p stroke="0.2" fill="true" strokecolor="yellow" color="blue" style="font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:26pt;">You can set a full page background.</p>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Print a text
$html = '<span style="background-color:yellow;color:blue;">&nbsp;PAGE 2&nbsp;</span>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// --- example with background set on page ---

// remove default header
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// -- set new background ---

// get the current page break margin
$bMargin = $pdf->getBreakMargin();
// get current auto-page-break mode
$auto_page_break = $pdf->getAutoPageBreak();
// disable auto-page-break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
// set bacground image
$img_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/holiday2012/happynewyearagat.png';
$pdf->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
// restore auto-page-break status
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
// set the starting point for the page content
$pdf->setPageMark();

// Print a text
$html = '<span style="color:white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:80pt;">PAGE 3</span>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// ---------------------------------------------------------
ob_clean();
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
?>
```

Но браузер выдает, что "Не удалось загрузить документ PDF"

Посмотрел на сервере, пдф созданный так и не нашел, значит даже до создания дело не дошло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как в вашем примере я избавился от этого только так но у меня вордпресс. Добавил `ob_end_clean();` перед `$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);`. Но у меня код выглядит по другому

```
ob_end_clean();
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
```

Comment: `file_exists` не бросает ошибок, `dirname(__FILE__)` успешно заменяется на `__DIR__`, который доступен уже лет десять.

Comment: Я работаю по документации :) взял пример от туда можете спорить с разработчиками.

Answer (score 0):

`PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION`, `PDF_UNIT`, `PDF_PAGE_FORMAT` и так далее —
это константы, которые вы не определили. Подключите файл конфигурации `tcpdf_config.php` и смотрите, какие константы есть.